# HOW TO Django OpenAPI Docs with Versioning

Tags: django-rest-framework, documentation, swagger-ui, openapi, versioning

Im trying to develop my first Django RESTFul API.
I have implemented some functionality and already got into Routing, Views, Serializers and so on.
Now i would like to setup some Documentation of everything i have currently implemented. So I have set up `drf_yasg` Swagger Documentation and added routes to the `swagger.json` and the swagger-ui.

**BUT**

The most important thing now: I need **Api Versioning**.
I have implemented two routes (v1 and v2) and the routing is fine.
But the documentation on the swagger site displays BOTH versions. and thats very very ugly.  Im now struggeling for hours to find a solution how swagger finds its versions to display on diffrent pages but theres really not documentation about this behavior.

Can anyone help out?

I come from .NET world and there I can implement Swagger with **ApiVersioning** and Swagger automatically make a dropdown into the ui for me where i can choose, which documentation i w ant to read

Thanks and I hope we can find a solution.